What is the difference between an ion and a radical?
I am a school student and thought that these were the same things, until I realized its not. I am unable to understand the main concept. Please provide me with a suitable explanation for my understanding.

Why did not searching for a ion and a radical bring enough understanding? // Review the guide How to ask and Asking FAQs to prevent clarification requests, objections,  downvoting or closure.

An ion is an atom or group of atoms that has a charge (so it isn't neutral). $\ce{Cl-}$ and $\ce{NH^+_4}$ are examples of ions. A radical is an ion, or molecule that has at least one unpaired valence electron. For example, nitric oxide $\ce{NO^.}$ is a radical since it (in this resonance structure) has an unpaired electron on nitrogen. An ion can be a radical (for example, the superoxide ion , $\ce{O^.-_2}$), but it certainly doesn't have to be (as depicted below, one form of molecular oxygen even is a diradical, $\ce{O^{2.}_2}$).



For future reference: for the body of questions, answers, and comments, chemistry.se offers to use mhchem as a comfortable method to add chemical equations and report numerical values (\pu{}) including a non-breakable space.

To highlight that "charge" (hence ion) and "unpaired electron" (hence radical) are two properties independent of each other, I edited your answer a little to highlight oxygen -- already depicted -- as a naturally occurring, persistent diradical.

Another common stable unionized radicals: CLO2 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chlorine_dioxide), See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_(chemistry)#History_and_nomenclature for how the meaning of radical has changed.

One more example of ionic radical is $\ce{[ON(SO3)2]^2−}$ in Fremy's salt.

Sulfur mononitride is also another candidate but is transient and only has been detected in outer space.
